# Is it possible to build Apps comatible for Mac OS 10.6 using Electron?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am new to Electron. Building OSX apps using Electron is easy. However, I couldn't make the app compatible with OSX 10.6 and higher. Is there a way to do this? The Default build targets latest version of OSX. I want to make it compatible with Mac OS 10.6 and higher.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Electron requires macOS 10.8 or higher, see [the docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/development/build-instructions-osx/). But Snow Leopard and Lion have a combined marketshare of ≈[1%](https://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=10&qpcustomd=0).